# i want to test react app with protractor but want to test by component name not by css selectors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protractor

i'm writing this line to expect a result this line works when i use css selector but not working with properties because value gets updated and write now i'm confirming it with oracle
expect(await element(by.react('t',{value:any })).getText()).toEqual('42');
error: no element found using locator: by.react('t',"[object Object]")
here is the link to the calculator app
https://ahfarmer.github.io/calculator/
kindly check and tell me how can I pick this up with component name instead of css name
await element(by.css('.component-display')) this line works but as I said I want to work with component props and states. I even tried value:'' but it still does not work. I don't want to write value:'42', I want to pick any value it currently do have.